# Store image in SQL Server

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

What is the difference between 1st col and 2nd col

```
select cast(img as varchar(max)), img 
from table_name;
```

I want to store images in SQL Server.

Which of the following is appropriate?

```
varbinary v/s nvarchar
```

Using SQL Server 2008

Comment: @marc_s Thanks .. Can you also answer the first part and add your comment too.So that I can accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an image is **binary** data, you should definitely pick `VARBINARY(MAX)` to store it inside your SQL Server table. `(N)VARCHAR` is for textual data (*not* binary).

For the same reason, the first part of your query

```
SELECT CAST(img AS varchar(max)),
```

really makes no sense - what to you expect when you're casting **binary data** into textual form? It will be gibberish that you get - no useful information...